# Why no error is thrown in compilation or running

Tags: c, arrays

```
int main()
{
    int a[2] = {1,2};
    a[2] = 3;
    printf("\n\n%d  %d  %d\n\n",a[0],a[1],a[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

I get output as `1 2 3`

Why no error is thrown at run time or compile time?

Comment: What language? This could actually work in a few different languages ...

Comment: Since no one has mentioned that it's undefined behaviour, I'll do that.

Answer (score 13):

Have you heard about all the security problems caused by *buffer overruns*? They exist because C doesn't have any automatic array bounds checking. It's the programmer's responsibility to ensure that they don't address outside the array limit, the compiler doesn't check for it.

Comment: C doesn't *require* automatic array bounds checking. Attempting to access an array outside its bounds has *undefined behavior*. A C compiler could legally implement bounds checking, but most don't

Comment: And obviously his doesn't, which explains what he sees.

Comment: @Barmar, I think it's also important to note that its technically undefined behaviour as another variable/constant (from a future stack frame or previous stack frame) could be constantly writing and reading to/from a subset of that block of memory -- meaning he should not always expect that result.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you don't address anything out of the boundary since, C doesn't check array bounds.

Answer (score 0):

`int a[2]` is allocated as an automatic variable on the stack.  In Windows the stack is initially allocated as 1MB for a process.  So, what has really happened is that when the code assigned `a[2] = 3;` an area outside of the stack frame for `main()` was updated.

More often than not this causes a problem, such as a segmentation fault, but in simple programs stuff like this sometimes still works.

An interesting test would be to call a sub-routine that also defines and sets some automatic variables and after it returns print the value of `a[2]` to see if it got overwritten by the stack frame for the sub-routine?  If you do this, please let me know the results!